# Ruby / Sinatra - "Application error" with json

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I have an "Aplication Error" with this lines :

```
get '/' do
  time = Time.new
  content_type :json
  returnValue = { "day" => "%02d" % time.day, "month" => "%02d" % time.month, "year" => #{time.year} }\
.to_json
  "#{returnValue}"
end
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part:

```
{time.year}
```

is not a valid Ruby object.

---

**Reflecting the edit in the question**

The part:

```
"year" => #{time.year}
```

is the same as

```
"year" =>
```

which does not close the hash, and is not a valid Ruby object.

Comment: Ok I found it, it's not `#{time.year}`, but `"#{time.year}"`